# Algorithm to compute sequences of zeros and ones by a specific order

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to write an algorithm `next()` to compute the next sequence with the following rules of order:

1. All sequences are of length `n` and composed of `0`s and `1`s.
2. A sequence with less `1`s will be before a sequence with more `1`s
3. A sequence with more `1`s to the left will be before a sequence with less `1`s to the left among sequences with the same number of `1`s (i.e, if comparing element by element from left to right, the first one to have a `1` where the other has a `0` will be first)

The output for `n=4` when calling `next()` `15` times will be:

```
0000
1000
0100
0010
0001
1100
1010
1001
0110
0101
0011
1110
1101
1011
0111
1111
```

Every call to `next()` should update a static variable to hold the last result. the first `0`s sequence will be generated beforehand and should fix the length.

I'm trying to implement this in Java so I would prefer finding one in Java, though this isn't crucial, since the main issue is the logic.

My main idea was to shift the rightmost `1`, but the main problem is how to deal with the case where there is a `1` in the right most position, and I can't quite get the pattern of how to move on from these cases.

This is my attempt but it might have some flaws that I'm not sure how to debug. also, I think this can be done more nicely than what I did here:

```
public static int[] next() {
    int i = last_res.length - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
        if (last_res[i] == 1) {
            last_res[i] = 0;
            if (i + 1 < last_res.length) {
                last_res[i + 1] = 1;
                return last_res;
            } else {
                i--;
                while (i >= 0) {
                    if (last_res[i] == 1) {
                        last_res[i + 1] = 1;
                        return last_res;
                    }
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
        i--;
    }
    last_res[0] = 1;
    return last_res;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: Shouldn't `n` be `4` for your output?

Comment: So for an existing input of last_res, there's three options: 1) there's a "more significant" solution with the same number of 1s. 2) you need more 1s and start with least significant solution for that number of 1s or 3) your result is all 1s and your're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would solve your problem - yet there's no recursion in there :-)

Plus there's no static variable for current value - instead I'd pass the current value to compute the next... but maybe that'll help you with your task.

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int n = 10;         
        //if n was dynamic, you'd compute that to have exact number.
        String current = leastSignificantForN(n, 0); 
        while(countOnes(current) < n) {
            System.out.println(current);
            current = next(current);
        }
        System.out.println(current);
    }

    private static String next(String current) {
        long co = countOnes(current);
        if(isMostSingificantForN(current, co)) {
            return leastSignificantForN(current.length(), co+1);
        } else {
            return increaseSignificance(current);
        }
    }

    private static String increaseSignificance(String current) {
        //Look for "moveable" 1
        int idx = current.lastIndexOf("01");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //Kepp string to the left intact
        for(int i = 0; i < idx; ++i) {
            sb.append(current.charAt(i));
        }
        sb.append("10");
        for(int i = idx + 2; i < current.length(); ++i) {
            sb.append(current.charAt(i));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String leastSignificantForN(int targetLength, long length) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < targetLength - length; ++i) {
            sb.append('0');
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            sb.append('1');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static boolean isMostSingificantForN(String current, long co) {
        int pos = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while(pos < current.length() && current.charAt(pos++) == '1') {
            ++count;
        }
        return count == co;
    }

    private static long countOnes(String current) {
        return current.chars().filter(i -> '1' == i).count();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very clean solution, but you will calculate all the values upfront, so if performance is a problem, other approach should be considered.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int size = 4;
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            calculateChances(size - i, i, "", results);
        }
        results.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void calculateChances(int zeroes, int ones, String current, List<String> results) {
        if (zeroes == 0 && ones == 0) {
            results.add(current);
            return;
        }
        if (ones > 0) {
            calculateChances(zeroes, ones - 1, current + "1", results);         
        }
        if (zeroes > 0) {
            calculateChances(zeroes - 1, ones, current + "0", results);         
        }       
    }
```

If you want a simple implementation of next, you can just create an iterator from the results list.